# how to find part number for slide-out tray cover that has cigarette lighter

Tags: parts, buick, century

I have a 2003 Buick Century. The cigarette lighter is located within this tray as part of the dashboard at the bottom (below the radio). This tray pulls out and it has this stiff piece of plastic at the front that functions as a cover. The plastic cover has weakened for me and it broke off. I'm trying to find a replacement and on the back of the cover it says the following:

```
VT 2425
10254271
Retainer - 1/P Ashtray Door
ABS + PC 002
```

I've been unsuccessful at googling and searching car part websites for this part. I was hoping someone could guide me a bit.

Thanks,

mj

Comment: Are you sure the second number in your list is correct? GM places the parts number on almost everything (if not *everything*) which they produce or install on their vehicles. The number you posted seems correct, except it has 8 numbers, where most GM PNs are 7 digits.

Comment: @Paulster2 yup, it's eight digits all right. 10254271

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the part number for the tray cover. They sell an assembly 10264371 that is the whole assembly. The cover does not seem to be for sale except maybe an used one on Ebay.

Comment: Hey! 5 years later and I get an answer! Too bad I don't have the car anymore :). Thanks!